# Connection timeout Symfony2 Swiftmailer and Outlook

Tags: php, symfony, email, outlook, swiftmailer

I have a connection timeout when I want to send an email with Outlook via Swiftmailer for Symfony2...

> Connection could not be established with host smtp-mail.outlook.com
>   [Connection timed out #110]

I read a lot of things here and on internet, but nothing worked... 
But I tried to set Thunderbird with that account, and it worked (the soft used STARTTLS instead of TLS).

Here are my parameters :

```
dev_mailer_transport: smtp
dev_mailer_host: smtp-mail.outlook.com
dev_mailer_port: 587
dev_mailer_user: USERNAME
dev_mailer_password: PASSWORD
```

Here is my config :

```
swiftmailer:
    encryption: tls
    auth_mode: login
```

And here is the code used to send an email :

```
$message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
                        ->setSubject($subject)
                        ->setFrom("no-reply@test.com")
                        ->setTo($data["email"])
                        ->setBody(nl2br($content), 'text/html');
$this->container->get('mailer')->send($message);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's working for me is with config.yml:

```
swiftmailer:
    transport:          "%mailer_transport%"
    host:               "%mailer_host%"
    port:               "%mailer_port%"
    username:           "%mailer_user%"
    password:           "%mailer_password%"
    encryption:         "%mailer_encryption%"
    delivery_address:   "%mailer_delivery_adress%"
```

And parameters.yml:

```
mailer_transport: smtp
mailer_host: smtp.office365.com
mailer_port: 587
mailer_user: user@example.com
mailer_password: mypassword
mailer_encryption: tls
mailer_delivery_adress: someadress@example.com
```

**Be also aware that there are a couple of restrictions given by Microsoft in terms of size, frequency and load to their mail servers.**

My example is given for Outlook365 instead of Outlook.com but the only difference is the exact smtp server adress.

Comment: Thanks !
After some research, I found that Cloud9 (a development environment, in the cloud) block mails via smtp. It seems that only the "gmail" transport method is authorized.
I will deploy my app on a server and directly try my code.